# FileOutputStream access is denied : JAVA

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I have the following code with the iText library properly integrated.

```
import java.io.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

@org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault(true)
public class HelloWorld {      
    public static final String RESULT = "C:\\Users\\administrator\\Pictures\\tuto";

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
        document.close(); 
    }
}
```

This code returns me an error message, which is as follows.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\valentin.schaefer\Pictures\tuto (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:25)
```

Yet I am the computer administrator and I normally have all permissions account. I don't understand why he retourn me `Access is denied`.

Comment: Does the directory exist?

Comment: Did you try accessing file from somewhere outside user space? or different drive?

Comment: yes, the directory exist and the folder have fool permissions

Comment: it looks like you may be pointing to a directory. Try ensuring that the `RESULT` is pointed at a non existent file or one that can be edited and saved.

Comment: offtopic: your logs contain your personal data. I suggest posting the logs anonymized.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are trying to access the directory. The parameter of the FileOutputStream should be a `File`/ `Path` object **pointing** to a file:

```
 FileOutputStream file  = new FileOutputStream("path/file.txt");
                   File -------------------------------^
```

For more detail take a look on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to have permission to access that file location. There are two possible solutions.

```
1. use deferent file location to store your file (eg: D:\\somewhere)  
2. make sure that you have permission to access current location by granting 
   read write permissions.
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to access directory using FileOutputStream( )
means you are trying to access directory "C:\Users\administrator\Pictures\tuto"
using -

```
public static final String RESULT = "C:\\Users\\administrator\\Pictures\\tuto";
new FileOutputStream(RESULT);
```

Which is wrong as the valid input which can be provided to FileOutputstream( ) is either file name (like "xyz.txt") or path of file (like "C:\sample\xyz.txt").

> > Use file name OR file path with FileOutputstream( ) and your problem will solve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in which I unzipped a jar file which failed due to this error message. This jar was a jar with dependencies and I had recently added a new dependency. After examining the jar contents, it turned out I had a `LICENSE` file and a folder `license` in the same root. While this is completely valid on Linux, the Windows file system will barf. The work around in my case to was trap this error in a try/catch. In the catch, check if you're on windows, if so log warning as there's not much that can be done, otherwise throw.

Answer (score 0):

**Not the answer from this question**

I got the same exception because Windows is not case sensitive.
Trying to create one file named "test" and other named "TEST" will generate the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if(!file.canRead()){
    file.setReadable(true);
 }

 FileOutputStream file  = new FileOutputStream("path/file.txt");
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code only answer and provide some explanation to clarify your answer.

Answer (score 0):

by this, you can change access to your file or folder dynamically.
Note: this will work on Linux machine only.

```
private void filePermissions(File filePath) throws IOException {

        Path path = Paths.get(filePath.toString());

        Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(path, PosixFileAttributes.class)
                .permissions();

        perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
        perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
        perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE);
        perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_WRITE);
        perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
        perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_EXECUTE);
        perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_WRITE);
        perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
        perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_EXECUTE);
        java.nio.file.Files.setPosixFilePermissions(path, perms);

    }
```